# multiplying rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
0        0.000313
1        0.316426
2        0.000313
3        0.004389
4        0.000000
5        0.004389
```

How can I create a dataframe that multiplies and takes the square root of every 2 rows?

For example, for the first 2 rows, it would do this: sqrt(0.000313*0.316426)

It should like this:

```
0        0.009951
1        0.001172
2        0.000000
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tries so far?

Comment: Multiplies by what? Could you clarify what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Multiply them with each other. I gave an example to hopefully clarify it.

Comment: I think your example should be:  sqrt(0.000313*0.316426) - Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you need is multiplying odd indexed element with even and take sqrt of them:

```
print(s)
```

Output:

```
0    0.000313
1    0.316426
2    0.000313
3    0.004389
4    0.000000
5    0.004389
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

And then,

```
pd.Series(np.sqrt([a*b for a,b in zip(list(s[::2]),list(s[1::2]))]))
```

Output:

```
0    0.009952
1    0.001172
2    0.000000
dtype: float64
```